# login to a website with VBA ie

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, authentication

I need to login in a website.
Every time I make the credential insterted with VBA, after the click event, It say that the password is not correct.

If I make the credential inserted by VBA and if I manually cancel one letter of the username and I rewrite it and if I manually cancel one letter of the password and I rewrite it, after I send the click event with VBA it works.

which is the reason? Shound I insert the credential using kinda keypress event? Which is the correct syntax for that?

thanks

please see below HTML code and what I wrote in VBA

```
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "sss.html"

    Do Until .ReadyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
    .Document.all.Item("login").Value = "username"
    .Document.all.Item("password").Value = "password"
Set elems = ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("button")
For Each e In elems
    If (e.innerHTML = "Confirm") Then
        e.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next e

<input type="text" ng-model="login" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" id="login" placeholder="Enter login (email)">
<input type="password" ng-model="password" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" id="password" placeholder="Password">
<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="authenticate()" notranslate="">Confirm</button>
```

Comment: I'd guess there is some event handler attached to the inputs which is causing that problem - it's expecting users to type, and you're not typing...  Without a URL though it's difficult to make useful suggestions.

Comment: tried. Does not work. give me an error saying that method or property is not supported by the object

Comment: URL is here        http://my.nuvap.com/home.html#/login

Comment: anyone can help, please?

Answer (score 0):

this website wants you to actually type your username/password and actually press the "Confirm" button, you can imitate it with `SendKeys`

so instead of setting the `value` and looping for the button element, use this code:

```
.Document.all.Item("login").focus
SendKeys "username", True
.Document.all.Item("password").focus
SendKeys "password", True
SendKeys "{TAB}", True
SendKeys "~", True
```

hope this helps.